# Css curvy footer

Tags: css, background, border

It is possible to achieve this footer only with css?
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Please read [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this:

```css
.container {
  background: yellow;
  height: 180px;
  width: 400px;
}

.box {
  width:400px;
  height:80px;
  background-color: white;
  border:1px solid white;
  border-width:0 0 13px 0;
  margin:1rem auto;
  -webkit-border-radius:0% 0% 50% 50% / 0% 0% 50% 50%;
  -moz-border-radius:0% 0% 50% 50% / 0% 0% 50% 50%;
  border-radius:0% 0% 50% 50% / 0% 0% 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"><div class="box"></div></div>
```